# Loading correct php.ini file on mac catalina for imap functionality

Tags: php, imap

I've been working for about 2 days now to simply get php imap working on my local site via macbook with catalina OS.

I finally got php-imap installed through homebrew but I still never saw the imap module loaded with phpinfo() on my web page. I realized it had no configuration file loaded. So now, while in my project folder, I run php --ini and get this:

[image]

I think my only issue now is that it's not actually loading an .ini file, but I could be wrong. I do know that the ini file in the etc/php7.3 folder has the imap extension line uncommented.

What should I do at this point?

Comment: what is the content of your imap.ini file? specifically, is an extension loaded?

Comment: @ArSeN the  ext-imap.ini file at usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d shows ```extension=/usr/local/opt/php@7.3-imap/lib/php/20180731/imap.so```

Comment: And does that file exist? Also, what does `php -i | grep imap` show?